# SAP UI5 vs web dynpro

Tags: sapui5, webdynpro

I am new in SAP.but i am confused b/w SAP UI5 and Webdynpro.I have some points of confusion.
(1) Is Webdynpro plays role like Servlets and JSP for middle ware programming.
(2) IS UI5 is replacement of Webdynpro.
(3) or UI5 is only a like front end programming like HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT etc.

Comment: Hi. Please read http://openui5.org/. UI5 is a client side UI library, if you need more information, please try to be more specific in your questions. (Btw: I can answer quiestion 2: No)

Comment: SAPUI5 is a replacement for WebDynpro when it is concerned to web based frontend development.

Comment: I do not agree. SAPWebUI, UI5, WebDynpro, btw, also BSP, fiori and fiori like, all are different approaches for enabling SAP-Gui functionalities inside another container, than simply sap gui. BTW, the downvotes are not necessary. Surely, one can say, ui5 is a new technique, but actual replacement for webdynpro....  I did not read about it untikl now, so for me it is no direct replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find comments below for your questions:

---

**(1) Is Webdynpro plays role like Servlets and JSP for middle ware programming?**
Not Exactly, Web Dynpro ABAP is the SAP standard UI technology for developing Web applications in the ABAP environment. It consists of a runtime environment and a graphical development environment with special Web Dynpro tools that are integrated in the ABAP Workbench.It enables you to build business applications, which means that you can't change the look and feel with embedded HTML or Java Script.

---

**(2) IS UI5 is replacement of Webdynpro.**

No, UI5 is a JavaScript UI Library.
UI5 lets you build enterprise-ready web applications, responsive to all devices, running on almost any browser of your choice. It’s based on JavaScript, using JQuery as its foundation and follows web standards. It eases your development with a client-side HTML5 rendering library including a rich set of controls and supports data binding to different models (JSON, XML and OData)
With respect to END user you may quite true. But for a developer WebDynpro and UI5 are two different UI technologies.

---

**(3) or UI5 is only a like front end programming like HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT etc.**

Yes, Its a JavaScript UI framework/library along with that it supports data binding to your different data models as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the comments below ( considering the differences between Web Dynpro and SAP UI5 ) :

1. Web Dynpro :ABAP framework to build web apps.

SAP UI5 : A Javascript application framework to build Web apps.

2. Web Dynpro does not play the role of a servlet/JSP as it is a complete UI technology for front-end development in ABAP. ( ABAP programming alongside plays a role of APIs ).
   UI5 is a javascript framework makes efficient use of oData services(http rest API) to create template-based front-end applications as well. 
   Here, oData is mainly ABAP Gateway oData or HANA XS oData which serves as APIs residing only in the application layer.